# How to get an ordered, limited, and grouped count from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

**Questions** have a column called **topic**.

People can assign a question a topic from an existing list like "Ruby on Rails", "Javascript", etc.

How can I get a **descending and limited** count of how many topics exist for each question?

**Desired result:**

```
{"Ruby on Rails" => 530,
"Javascript" => 509,
"Node.jS" => 483}
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(1) as questions_with_topic, 
  topic
FROM questions
GROUP BY topic
ORDER BY questions_with_topic DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**Rails: (I don't know how to order or limit it)**

```
Question.group(:topic).count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Question.limit(10).group(:topic).order(:topic).count
```

That orders by "topic ASC".

To explicitly specify order direction you can do this:

```
Question.limit(10).group(:topic).order("topic DESC").count
```

And to order by count, do this:

```
Question.limit(10).group(:topic).order("COUNT(*) ASC").count
```

Comment: "Topic" is actually just a column in the "Question" table :)

Comment: Thanks! also how do you add in the order of it?

Comment: The limit works, but the ordering does not yet. I think this is ordering "topic" alphabetically, instead of the number of "questions" with a topic.

Comment: Yeah. Just change the ordering to "COUNT(*)"